# Can Go module Checksum verification be bypassed?

Tags: go, go-modules

I am experimenting with the [Cosmos SDK](https://github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk) written in Go.  The SDK is used in a different module (via `require` directive in `go.mod`).

I will call this **module x**.  If any changes are made to the SDK (in `$GOPATH/pkg/mod/github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk@v0.44.5`), compilation of **module x** fails due to a checksum mismatch (it complains that the cosmos-sdk directory has been modified).

I have looked around and there are proper ways of managing this, but how can this verification step be bypassed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use the [replace directive](https://go.dev/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace) in your `go.mod` and point it at the locally modified source code path.

Comment: I just cloned the repo and added the replace directive `replace github.com/cosmos/cosmos-sdk => /path/to/cosmos-sdk`.  Everything works as expected now.  Thanks!